# Color image segmentation with Ward clustering in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the Ward method in sklearn to segment a color image.  I've been working from the sklearn example that segments a grayscale image (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_lena_ward_segmentation.html#example-cluster-plot-lena-ward-segmentation-py), but I can't seem to get it to work with color.

Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import grid_to_graph
from sklearn.cluster import Ward

img = Image.open("test.jpg")
img = np.array(img)

X = img.reshape((-1, 3))
x, y, z = img.shape

connectivity = grid_to_graph(n_x=x, n_y=y, n_z=z)
ward = Ward(n_clusters=5, connectivity=connectivity).fit(X)
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#421>", line 1, in <module>
    ward = Ward(n_clusters=5, connectivity=connectivity).fit(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\hierarchical.py", line 370, in fit
    raise ValueError("`connectivity` does not have shape "
ValueError: `connectivity` does not have shape (n_samples, n_samples)
```

I've tried a few other things but nothing seems to work.  Thanks!

UPDATE

I could've sworn I tried this before, but apparently omitting the n_z parameter in the call to grid_to_graph solves the problem:

```
connectivity = grid_to_graph(n_x=x, n_y=y)
ward = Ward(n_clusters=5, connectivity=connectivity).fit(X)
```

If anyone can confirm or deny that this is still doing what I'm trying to accomplish, that'd be great!

Comment: You should consider posting your update as an answer if it solved your problem